# Who, if anyone, held the mantle of Black Panther after N'Jakada's successful challenge?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther-2018

In the *Black Panther* movie, N'Jakada's successfully challenges T'Challa and becomes King of Wakanda. He also attempted to widen the scope of his challenge to also include T'Challa's role as the Black Panther.

> N'JAKADA: I am N'Jadaka, son of Prince N'Jobu. [...] I'm exercising my blood right to challenge for the mantles of king... and Black Panther.

In the customary ceremony before the fight, T'Challa is (for the second time in the movie) separated from the supportive power of the Black Panther.

N'Jadaka clearly becomes king, but it is unclear to me whether he becomes Black Panther, or whether T'Challa later somehow regains the power of the Black Panther. Who, if anyone, held the mantle of Black Panther after N'Jakada's successful challenge?

Comment: "is unclear to me whether he becomes Black Panther, or whether T'Challa later somehow regains the power of the Black Panther" Why unclear? Killmonger did get the power and the suit and T'Challa regained it - it was supposed to be clear.

Comment: He also really ostentatiously has the garden where the herb that grants the powers of the Black Panther grows burnt to the ground. That whole scene seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 2):

For as long as there had been a King of Wakanda they also held the title of Black Panther. So when N'Jadaka defeats T'Challa, he takes the title of Black Panther along with the kingship. He then  takes the fluid of the heart-shaped herb which gives the Black Panther his power.

T'Challa later regains both titles by essentially challenging and defeating N'Jadaka.